# How to write solution of a maze to file in c in c

Tags: c

so im working on an assignment that is due todoay. 
The program should read a text file , extract 7 Strings , each representing a possible Labyrinth.
Then for each String , we see if it can build a solvable maze ( one accessible entrance , one exit and a square shape ) . If its invalid i should write it down in the exit file with an error message specifying the error otherwise transform the string to 2D array , replace charachters then solve it and put it in file .

Im stuck now on handling all the files. although i put them in an array then i made a loop to treat all string , the output file is always empty or sometimes filled with one error msg.

please help guys this assignment is due tomorrow and this last minute change was requested by the professor .

this is the code so far :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define Max 200

typedef struct {
    char labName[4];
    char ch[Max];
} Labyrinth;


void explore(int x, int y, int count, int squareRoot, char **maze, int **temp) {

//wir pruefen ob wir nicht die Grenzung der Matrize überschritten haben
    if (x >= 0 && x < squareRoot && y >= 0 && y < squareRoot) {
//wenn wir das Ziel erreicht haben, testen wir den count mit dem neuen, wenn der neue minimal ist als der alte, verwenden wir ihn
        if (maze[x][y] == 'z' && temp[x][y] > count) {
            temp[x][y] = count;
        }
// wenn maze[x][y]=o , das heißt dass wir dieses Feld schon besucht haben, wir pruefen ob der count minimal als der frueheren count
        else if (maze[x][y] == 'o' && temp[x][y] > count) {
            temp[x][y] = count;
        }
//wenn wir in ein leeres Feld maze[x][y]==' ' wir markieren ihn als besucht maze[x][y]='o';
        else if (maze[x][y] == ' ' || maze[x][y] == 'b') {
            if (maze[x][y] != 'b') {
                maze[x][y] = 'o';
            }
            if (maze[x][y] == 'b') {
                count = 0; // iniziale count gleich 0
            }

            if (temp[x][y] > count || temp[x][y] < 0)
                temp[x][y] = count;
            count++; // nach jede Exploration addieren wir 1
            explore(x - 1, y, count, squareRoot, maze, temp); // exploration der oberen Felder
            explore(x, y + 1, count, squareRoot, maze, temp); // exploration der Felder nach Recht
            explore(x + 1, y, count, squareRoot, maze, temp); // exploration der Unteren Felder
            explore(x, y - 1, count, squareRoot, maze, temp); //exploration der Felder nach Links

        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int min = 0;           // Anzahl der Schritten
    char ** maze = NULL;   // Die Matrize,die die labyrinth enthaelt
    char ** res = NULL; // Die Matrize, die die Lösung des minimales weg ausgibt
    int **temp = NULL;   // Matrize fuer die Berechnung und die Datenbearbeitung
    int squareRoot = 0;        // Wurzel des Strings
    int xb = 0, yb = 0, xz = 0, yz = 0; // Koordinaten des Startes und Endes
    int i = 0;
    int m = 0;           //Zähler
    int key = 0;          //Falg , entweder 0 oder 1
    Labyrinth* Lab = NULL; //Array fürs Speichern die eingelesene Daten aus der Datei

    char ch[Max] = { 0 };  //speichert die labyrinth
    FILE* IN = NULL;       // labyrinthe.txt
    FILE* OUT = NULL;   // Losüng.txt
    char fileName[256];

//Speicherreservierung fuer Array Lab
    Lab = (Labyrinth*) malloc(sizeof(Labyrinth) * 10);

    //wie lesen die Name der Datei von console
    printf("\nPlease enter the name of the  file containing a labryinth:\n");
    scanf("%255s", fileName);
    if ((IN = fopen(fileName, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("\nCould not open file.\n");
        return 0;
    }

// wir verwenden fscanf, um bis zum Ende der Datei zu lesen, und suchen nach einem geeigneten Labyrinth, wenn dieses gefunden wird, wird es in ch abgespeichert
    while (fscanf(IN, "%2s=%[^\n]s", Lab[m].labName, Lab[m].ch) != EOF) {
        printf("%s=%s\n", Lab[m].labName, Lab[m].ch);
        m++;
    }
    OUT = fopen("solved.txt", "w");

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {

        key = 0;
        strcpy(ch, Lab[i].ch);
// die Wurzel der Länge der gewählten Zeichenkette berechnen
        squareRoot = sqrt(strlen(ch));
// die Entfernung zwischen Start und Ziel
        min = Max;
// Pruefung ob wir die Forme eine labyrinth haben
        if (strlen(ch) != pow(squareRoot, 2)) {
            fprintf(OUT, "%s=%s", Lab[i].labName, Lab[i].ch);
            fprintf(OUT, "%s", "!! ERROR : NUMBER OF ELEMENTS INSUFFICIENT  !!\n\n");
            key = 1;
        } else if (strchr(ch, 'b') == NULL) { // wir testen die Existenz eines Ausgangspunkts
      printf("%s",  Lab[i].ch);
            fprintf(OUT, "%s",  Lab[i].ch);
            fprintf(OUT, "%s", "!! ERROR : NO ENTRANCE FOUND !!\n\n");

            key = 1;
        } else if (strchr(ch, 'z') == NULL) { // wir testen die Existenz eines Zielpunktes
            fprintf(OUT, "%s=%s", Lab[i].labName, Lab[i].ch);
            fprintf(OUT, "%s", "!! ERROR : NO EXIT FOUND !!\n\n");
            key = 1;
        } else {
//Speicherzuordnung fur die Matrizen
            maze = (char * *) malloc(squareRoot * sizeof(char * *));
            res = (char * *) malloc(squareRoot * sizeof(char * *));
            temp = (int * *) malloc(squareRoot * sizeof(int * *));

//Wir bilden die Lybrinthe aus der Matrix, indem wir die Zeichen ersetzen
            for (int i = 0; i < squareRoot; i++) {
                maze[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * squareRoot);
                res[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * squareRoot);
                temp[i] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * squareRoot);
                for (int j = 0; j < squareRoot; j++) {
                    if (ch[i * squareRoot + j] == 'b') { //die Koordinaten des Eingangs b finden
                        maze[i][j] = 'b'; //wir fügen das Zeichen 'b' in diese Koordinaten fuer die maze Matrix ein
                        res[i][j] = 'b'; //wir fügen die Buchstabe b in die Eingefundene Koordinaten fuer die maze res ein
                        temp[i][j] = 0; //wir fügen 0 in die gefundene koordinaten
                        yb = j;
                        xb = i;
                        if (xb != 0 && yb != 0 && xb != squareRoot - 1
                                && yb != squareRoot - 1) {

                            fprintf(OUT, "%s=%s", Lab[i].labName, Lab[i].ch);
                            fprintf(OUT, "%s",
                                    "Error : Entrance must be accessible !!\n\n");
                            key = 1;
                            i = j = 1000;
                            break;

                        } else if ((xb == 0 && yb == 0)
                                || (xb == 0 && yb == squareRoot - 1)
                                || (xb == squareRoot - 1 && yb == 0)
                                || (xb == squareRoot - 1 && yb == squareRoot - 1)) {

                            fprintf(OUT, "%s=%s", Lab[i].labName, Lab[i].ch);
                            fprintf(OUT, "%s",
                                    "Error : Entrance cannot be in the corners !!\n\n");
                            key = 1;
                            i = j = 1000;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    else if (ch[i * squareRoot + j] == 'z') { //die Koordinaten des Ausgangs z finden
                        maze[i][j] = 'z'; // wir fuegen  z in den gefundene Koordinaten fuer maze matrix ein
                        res[i][j] = 'z'; // wir fuegen  z in den gefundene Koordinaten fuer res matrix ein
                        temp[i][j] = Max; //wir fuegen Max =200 eine grosse Zahl fuer die inizialisierung in die gefundene Koordinaten
                        xz = i;
                        yz = j;
                    } else if (ch[i * squareRoot + j] == 'k') { // Positionen der Leerzeichene finden und dann mit ' ' ersetzen
                        maze[i][j] = ' ';
                        res[i][j] = ' ';
                        temp[i][j] = -1; // leerzeichen =-1
                    } else if (ch[i * squareRoot + j] == 'w') { // Positionen des Wandes finden und dann mit '#' ersetzen
                        maze[i][j] = '#';
                        res[i][j] = '#';
                        temp[i][j] = -2; // wand =-2
                    } else if (ch[i * squareRoot + j] == 's') { //genesen der Position der Sackgasse
                        maze[i][j] = 's';
                        res[i][j] = 's';
                        temp[i][j] = -3; // Sackgasse = -3
                    } else {
                        printf("Error!!\n");
                        return 0;
                    }

                }

            }
        }

        if (key == 0) {

//anfagen mit der Exploration ab das erste Feld b
            explore(xb, yb, 0, squareRoot, maze, temp);
            min = temp[xz][yz];

            if (min == Max) {
                printf("There is no solutuin to this maze!!");
            }
// else temp[xz][yz] enthalt der minimal cout von einen Weg
            else {

                int x = xz;
                int y = yz;
//in dieser Schleife werden wir die Felde deren Umgebung ist z besuchen
//wir versuchen, zurück zu gehen(Backtracking der path ) , um die Startbox zu finden
                while (x != xb || y != yb) {
//alle gefundene boxe bauen der minimalen weg
                    if (temp[x - 1][y] == temp[x][y] - 1) {

                        res[x - 1][y] = '+';
                        x = x - 1;
                    }

                    else if (temp[x + 1][y] == temp[x][y] - 1) {
                        res[x + 1][y] = '+';
                        x = x + 1;
                    }

                    else if (temp[x][y - 1] == temp[x][y] - 1) {
                        res[x][y - 1] = '+';
                        y = y - 1;
                    }

                    else if (temp[x][y + 1] == temp[x][y] - 1) {
                        res[x][y + 1] = '+';
                        y = y + 1;
                    }

                }
                res[xb][yb] = 'b';
                printf("The shortest path :\n\n");

// die loesung in ein Datei speichern

                for (int i = 0; i < squareRoot; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < squareRoot; j++) {

                        fprintf(OUT, "%c", res[i][j]);
                    }
                    fprintf(OUT, "\n");
                }

                fprintf(OUT, "The minimal number of steps is: %d;\n", min);
            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < squareRoot; i++) {
            char* currentIntPtr = maze[i];
            free(currentIntPtr);

            char* currentIntPtr2 = res[i];
            free(currentIntPtr2);

            int* currentIntPtr3 = temp[i];
            free(currentIntPtr3);

        }

    }
    fclose(IN);

    fclose(OUT);

}
```

Sample input file:

```
L3=wwwwwwwskkkwwwkwswwskwwwwwkkzwwwwwww 
L4=wwwwbwwskkkwwwkwswwskwwwwwkkswwwwwww 
L5=wwwbwwwskkkwwwwwswwskwwwwwkkzwwwwwww 
L6=wwwbwwkskkkwwwkwswwskwwwwwkkzwwwwwww 
L1=wwwbwwwskkkwwwkwswwskwwwwwkkzwwwwwww
L2=wwwwwwwwwswkkkswwkwkwzwwwkkkwwswbkwwswkwwkkkkwkwwswwkkkwwwwwwwww
L7=wwwbwwwwwskkkkkwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
```

thanks in advance and sorry if i messed up the form m this is my first post .

UPDATE  so i fixed a wrong counter and i believe the problem now is that the String are not being saved into the Lab array , so the rest of the program cant process it

Comment: Side note: if your professor does not explicitly insist on comments in German, I'd recommend getting used to writing them in English. (especially since your English is quite ok judging by this question, and your German comments contain lots of typos/grammar issues)

Comment: Could you provide some example files and associated output?

Comment: Also, split the parts into separate functions - this makes it easier to talk and to reason about it. For example, extract the part that saves your result to the file into a separate function, then you can test it in isolation from the parts that do the maze-solving.

Comment: yes i forgot about the input files too :  L3=wwwwwwwskkkwwwkwswwskwwwwwkkzwwwwwww
L4=wwwwbwwskkkwwwkwswwskwwwwwkkswwwwwww
L5=wwwbwwwskkkwwwwwswwskwwwwwkkzwwwwwww
L6=wwwbwwkskkkwwwkwswwskwwwwwkkzwwwwwww
L1=wwwbwwwskkkwwwkwswwskwwwwwkkzwwwwwww
L2=wwwwwwwwwswkkkswwkwkwzwwwkkkwwswbkwwswkwwkkkkwkwwswwkkkwwwwwwwww
L7=wwwbwwwwwskkkkkwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww

Comment: and what means w, b, s, k, what is supposed to look the maze

Comment: @Hulk for some reason im unable to do that, im in VM so everything feels a bit clumsy

Comment: @Mathieu so "w" is # a wall , b is the entrance , s i a dead end and k is like a corridor , simply empty space from wish you can continue .

Comment: @Mathieu this is an expected output for a valid String :                                                   ###b##
 s++ #
##+#s#
#s+###
##++z#
######
The minimal number of steps is: 7;                                                                                                                                 otherwise for example ;                                                                                                                                    L3=wwwwwwwskkkwwwkwswwskwwwwwkkzwwwwwww                                                    ERROR : NO ENTRANCE FOUND

Comment: its perfect thanks guys

Comment: @Hulk i cant find a way to seperate the save part from everything else , as i need to save either the maze trqnsformed to a 2d array or a an error msg and the input string